# Power bi DAX calculate the average of column from another table using surrogate key

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have two tables FACT AND DIM as follow:

[image]

the tables are linked to each other using the SRGT key.

**I want to calculate the average of ANSWER_VALUES**

I was able to do it with SQL using the query below:

```
  SELECT AVG(DIM.ANSWER_VALUE)
  FROM FACT_SURVEY FACT
  INNER JOIN DIM_QUESTION_ANSWER DIM
  ON FACT.ANSWER_SRGT = DIM.ANSWER_SRGT
```

I tried to write the DAX formula, but it didn't work:

```
AVGSCORE = 
VAR MTABLE = SUMMARIZE(FACT_SURVEY,FACT_SURVEY[RESPONDENT_SRGT])
VAR MTABLE0 = ADDCOLUMNS(MTABLE,"answer",CALCULATE(AVERAGE(FACT_SURVEY[ANSWER_SRGT])))
VAR AVGTABLE = ADDCOLUMNS(MTABLE0,"value",CALCULATE(AVERAGE(DIM_ANSWER[ANSWER_VALUE])))

RETURN  ???
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `AVERAGEX` with `RELATED`:

```
AVGSCORE :=
AVERAGEX(
    FACT_SURVEY,
    RELATED( DIM_ANSWER[ANSWER_VALUE] )
)
```